# Let (X, $\tau$) be a topological space and S a prescribed subset of X. Show that (S, $\tau_{rel} $) is a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove this, and would just like to confirm that my prove is valid.

> Definition: Let S be a subset of X and suppose that (X, $\tau$) is a topological space. Then the collection of subsets
>
> $\tau_{rel} = \left \{ S\cap O : O \in \tau_{x} \right \}$

In order to prove this, $\tau_{rel} $ must satisfy the 3 axioms:

(i) Obviously, this will be true because $S \cap X $ = S. And $S \cap \emptyset$ = $\emptyset$.

(ii) Take $y \in O_{x}  \land  y \in S$.
So, $y \in S\cap O_{x}$.
Therefore, $ y \in O_{rel}$.
Define $O_{x} = \bigcap_{i \in \tau_{x}}O_{i}$.
So, $\forall O_{i}$ we have $y \in O_{i}$.
Therefore, $y \in S \cap O_{i}$.
So, if we have some $O_{rel} \in \tau_{rel}$  where we define $O_{rel} = \bigcap_{i \in \tau_{rel}}O_{i}$, then $\forall y \in \tau_{rel}$ we also have y in an arbitrary intersection.

(iii) Do the same thing as above, but for union.

Is this valid?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using the closed or open definition for a topology? I posted a solution using the open set definition

Answer (score 1):

To show $S \in \tau_{rel}$ and $\emptyset \in \tau_{rel}$, as you noticed $X \cap S =S \in \tau_{rel}$ and $S \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \in \tau_{rel}$.

To show that an arbitrary union of a collection $\{O_i \cap S \}_{i \in I}$ of open sets  $O_i \cap S \in \tau_{rel}$ is in $\tau_{rel}$, notice

$$\bigcup_{i \in I} (O_i \cap S)= S \cap \bigcup_{i \in I} O_i.$$

But since $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ we have $\bigcup_{i \in I} O_i \in \tau$, implying $S \cap \bigcup_{i \in I} O_i \in \tau_{rel}$.

Lastly for intersections let $O \cap S$ and $U \cap S$ be elements of $\tau_{rel}$. Then

$$(O \cap S) \cap (U \cap S) = (O \cap U) \cap S.$$

But $O \cap U \in \tau$ implying $(O \cap U) \cap S \in \tau_{rel}$.